# MATHCOUNTS percentage question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

> Suppose that 6% of 8th graders and 3% of 7th graders from some school
>   participate in MATHCOUNTS. There are 1.5 times as many
>   8th graders as 7th graders at that school. What percentage of 7th
>   graders and 8th graders participate in MATHCOUNTS?

I've translated and solved this problem by letting the unknown be 7th graders, then solved it again by letting it be 8th graders and the answer was $4.8\%$. However I'm now attempting to solve this question by letting $x$ be students total.

If $x$ = students total

Then we have $0.06x$ and $0.03x$ of them participating. That makes $0.09x$.

> There are 1.5 times as many 8th graders as 7th graders at that school.

Since I defined $x$ to represent this amount the $\frac{0.09x}{1x}$ is just quotient identiy. I obviously did something wrong with the definitions.

Comment: If $x$ is the total of 7th and 8th graders, you do NOT have $0.06x$ 8th graders and $0.03x$ 7th graders participating.

Comment: I think they just want the weighted average of $6$ and $3$, right? (To me the question is somewhat confusing)

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch this was on percentage's section, don't think they wanted me to work with averages here.

Comment: I am saying the solution is the weighted average: $$\frac{1.5\cdot 6+1\cdot 3}{1.5+1}=\frac{24}5=4.8$$ in my opinion this question is maybe a misfit for the percentages category 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let e be the number of eight graders, s the number of seventh graders.
There are .08e eight graders and .03s seventh graders participating.
The percentage of particapting eight and seventh graders is
(.08e + .03s)/(e + s) the weighted average.
Using the additional given information,
determine the value of the weighted average.